# VFP OLEDB Error Building Key

Tags: visual-foxpro, foxpro

Using the VFPOLEDB Driver I am able to insert 1 record but after that record has been inserted I am receiving this error.

Source: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Visual FoxPro

Description: Error building key for index "c:\users\user\desktop\data\customer.cdx" tag "Customer".

Comment: What's the definition for the Customer tag? My best guess is that it's variable length, which is a bad idea and can cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  Possibility belongs to the CDX file

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/78826034-a0d4-4dc7-89a5-c8cf7e3d5b54/vfpoledb-got-error-building-key-for-index-when-inserting-new-row-in-my-dbf?forum=visualfoxprogeneral